# Android : How to wait until Timer and Timertask finish their work on UI Thread

Tags: android

I have a fragment. In this fragment, I have a Timer that run a timertask periodically. I override `onPause` so when switch fragment, TimerTask and timer will stop its work.

```
@Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            timerTask.cancel();
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
```

And Here is my code for switching fragment :

```
OrderFragment fragment2 = new OrderFragment();
                    fragment2.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment2).commit();
```

But when I switch different fragment, I often receive `Null Point Exception` because TimerTask cannot access UI Thread anymore (because I have used `runOnUIThread` )

So, my question is : How to be sure that Timer and TimerTask stop all its work, before I can change fragment.

Thanks :)

Comment: post the code of your fragment switch including the method on which it is

Comment: @Arju I have edited my post. please review it for me. thanks :)

Comment: Did you make sure that your onpause gets called ,debug it using a log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29) is what you need. From the `Fragment` `onPause()` documentation:

> This is generally tied to Activity.onPause of the containing
>   Activity's lifecycle.

So `onPause()` isn't necessarily called when the Fragment is no longer visible. Move your timer canceling code into `onHiddenChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment may not go into the background simply by switching the displayed fragment.  It's lifecycle is dependent on the Activity's.  I think if you add `Log.d("yourFragment", "onPause()");` to the onPause() method you'll find this to be true.

The fragment lifecycle can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Note that it says when your fragment is removed/replaced, but if you're merely displaying another fragment from your activity that doesn't count ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `timer`.cancle as a statement just above this as:

```
timer.cancel();
OrderFragment fragment2 = new OrderFragment();
                fragment2.setArguments(arguments);  
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container,      
fragment2).commit();


Declare private Timer timer; at class level
```